# Optimizing T-SQL Insert -- temptable, CTEs, WHILE loops

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a situation where I need to process and finally insert 1000s of records from a temptable into a database table. Before each insert, I need to ensure that conditions are met and right after each insert, I need to update a second table in my database. My problem is that currently, it takes approximately 25 minutes to run the query and I would like to drastically cut that time so my application can be more responsive. How can I go about doing this please?

```
DECLARE @rowcounter as INTEGER 


                    CREATE TABLE #temporary_phonetable 
                    (
                          rownumber int  not null  identity(1,1), 
                          record_no BIGINT,
                          phone_name BIGINT, 
                          phone_number Varchar(25)  not null  ,
                           responsemessage Varchar(200)  not null  ,
                          messagepriority Varchar(14)  not null  , 
                          phone_id BIGINT, 
                          AD_show  BIGINT, 
                          power_show Varchar(400), 
                          service_provider VARCHAR(30),
                          Phone_flag  VARCHAR(30),
                          questionMessage BIGINT,
                          PRIMARY KEY (phone_id, phone_number, rownumber)
                        ,UNIQUE (questionMessage, record_no, rownumber) 
                    )
                    --GET PHONE DATA 
                                --if phone numbers are sent in from the client, then we want to process those instead 
            IF ( ( ( @listofphones IS NULL OR LEN(@listofphones) <1) AND LEN(@peoplegroups) >0)  )
             BEGIN 
                   --NO PHONENUMBER BUT THERE ARE GROUPS AVAILABLE                        
                              INSERT INTO #temporary_phonetable(phone_name, phone_number, messagepriority, phone_id, AD_show, power_show, responsemessage) 
                              SELECT n.phone_name, n.phone_number,u.messagepriority, n.phone_id , u.AD_show, u.power_show , CASE  @includegreetings   WHEN 1 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(phone_name)) + @responsemessages 
                                      ELSE @responsemessages END as text_message
                              FROM user u WITH(NOLOCK) 
                              INNER JOIN Phonenumbers n  WITH(NOLOCK) ON n.user_no = u.user_no
                                INNER JOIN PeopleGroupRelations g ON  g.phone_id=n.phone_id  
                                INNER JOIN ( Select items FROM Split(@peoplegroups, @listofphonesdelimiter)) gg ON g.group_no = gg.items 
                              WHERE n.user_no=@userid 
                              AND n.status=''active''
                              SET @rowcounter = @@ROWCOUNT
             END 
             ELSE  IF ( LEN(@listofphones) >1  AND LEN(@peoplegroups) >0)
              BEGIN  
                      --PHONENUMBER AND GROUPS 
                              INSERT INTO #temporary_phonetable(phone_name, phone_number, messagepriority, phone_id, AD_show, power_show, responsemessage) 
                              SELECT n.phone_name, n.phone_number,u.messagepriority, n.phone_id , u.AD_show, u.power_show , CASE  @includegreetings   WHEN 1 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(phone_name)) + @responsemessages 
                                      ELSE @responsemessages END as text_message
                              FROM  Split(@listofphones, ''|'')  s
                              INNER JOIN PhoneNumbers n  WITH(NOLOCK) ON n.phone_number = s.items
                              INNER JOIN User u WITH(NOLOCK)  ON n.user_no =u.user_no
                              INNER JOIN PeoplegroupRelations g ON  g.phone_id=n.phone_id  
                              INNER JOIN ( Select items FROM Split(@peoplegroups, @listofphonesdelimiter)) gg ON g.group_no = gg.items 
                              WHERE n.user_no=@userid 
                              AND n.status=''active''
                              SET @rowcounter = @@ROWCOUNT
             END 
              ELSE  IF ( LEN(@listofphones) >1  AND LEN(@peoplegroups) >0)
              BEGIN  
                      --PHONENUMBER AND NO GROUPS 
                              INSERT INTO #temporary_phonetable(phone_name, phone_number, messagepriority, phone_id, AD_show, power_show, responsemessage) 
                              SELECT n.phone_name, n.phone_number,u.messagepriority, n.phone_id , u.AD_show, u.power_show , CASE  @includegreetings   WHEN 1 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(phone_name)) + @responsemessages 
                                      ELSE @responsemessages END as text_message
                              FROM  Split(@listofphones, ''|'')  s
                              INNER JOIN PhoneNumbers n  WITH(NOLOCK) ON n.phone_number = s.items
                              INNER JOIN User u WITH(NOLOCK)  ON n.user_no =u.user_no
                              INNER JOIN PeopleGroupRelations g ON  g.phone_id=n.phone_id  
                              INNER JOIN ( Select items FROM Split(@peoplegroups, @listofphonesdelimiter)) gg ON g.group_no = gg.items 
                              WHERE n.user_no=@userid 
                              AND n.status=''active''
                              SET @rowcounter = @@ROWCOUNT
             END  
             ELSE 
                    BEGIN 
                          -- NO PHONENUMBER NO GROUP --- IE. SEND TO ALL PHONE NUMBERS
                                 INSERT INTO #temporary_phonetable(phone_name, phone_number, messagepriority, phone_id, AD_show, power_show,responsemessage) 
                                SELECT   n.phone_name, n.phone_number,u.messagepriority, n.phone_id , u.AD_show, u.power_show , CASE  @includegreetings   WHEN 1 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(phone_name)) + @responsemessages 
                                      ELSE @responsemessages END as text_message
                                FROM User u  
                                          INNER JOIN PhoneNumbers n ON n.user_no = u.user_no
                                WHERE
                                        n.status=''active''
                                        AND  n.user_no=@userid 
                                    SET @rowcounter = @@ROWCOUNT 
                    END



                  IF( @rowcounter>0)
                  BEGIN 
                                    DECLARE @service_provider as Varchar(30)
                                    DECLARE @PhoneType as Varchar(30)

                                    IF (LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(@sendresponseswhen))) ='now')
                                    BEGIN 
                                                SET @dateresponsessent = GETDATE()
                                     END

                                                      DECLARE @rownumber int
                                                      DECLARE @power_show BIT
                                                      DECLARE  @AD_show BIT 
                                                      set @rownumber = 0 
                                                      WHILE @rownumber < @rowcounter
                                                      BEGIN
                                                                    set @rownumber = @rownumber + 1
                                                                    -- THE VARIABLES 
                                                                                DECLARE @record_no as BIGINT
                                                                                DECLARE @phone_name VARCHAR(30)
                                                                                DECLARE @messagepriority as INTEGER
                                                                                DECLARE @phone_number VARCHAR(30)
                                                                                DECLARE @phone_id BIGINT
                                                                                DECLARE @questionMessage BIGINT

                                                                     SELECT 
                                                                              @phone_name = n.phone_name, @phone_number =n.phone_number, @messagepriority =n.messagepriority, @phone_id=n.phone_id , 
                                                                              @AD_show=n.AD_show, @power_show=n.power_show
                                                                        FROM 
                                                                              #temporary_phonetable n WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                                                        WHERE n.rownumber = @rownumber

                                                                        SET @record_no = AddMessageToQueue(@phone_number, @responsemessages, @dateresponsessent, @savednames, @userid, un.messagepriority, @responsetype, 
                                                                        un.AD_show, un.power_show, @service_provider, @PhoneType)  


                                                                        If(@questionid > 0)
                                                                        BEGIN 
                                                                                SET @questionMessage = AddQuestionMessage(@questionid,@phone_id,  @record_no, DATEADD(d, 30, GETDATE()) )
                                                                        END 


                                                UPDATE #temporary_phonetable SET record_no = @record_no, questionMessage=@questionMessage WHERE phone_number = @phone_number  AND rownumber = @rownumber
                                    END 
                                    IF( @power_show >0)
                                    BEGIN 
                                          SET @responsemessages = @responsemessages + dbo.returnPoweredBy()
                                    END
                                    IF( @AD_show > 0)
                                    BEGIN 
                                          SELECT @responsemessages = @responsemessages + CASE 
                                                                                                            WHEN (LEN(@responsemessages)  + 14)<  160 THEN    dbo.returnAD(@responsemessages) 
                                                                                                            ELSE '''' END 
                                    END


                                    RETURN @rowcounter
                        END
```

I believe this is the place where the bulk of the issue resides.

WHILE @rownumber < @rowcounter
                                                      BEGIN
                                                                    set @rownumber = @rownumber + 1
                                                                    -- THE VARIABLES 
                                                                                DECLARE @record_no as BIGINT
                                                                                DECLARE @phone_name VARCHAR(30)
                                                                                DECLARE @messagepriority as INTEGER
                                                                                DECLARE @phone_number VARCHAR(30)
                                                                                DECLARE @phone_id BIGINT
                                                                                DECLARE @questionMessage BIGINT

```
                                                                 SELECT 
                                                                          @phone_name = n.phone_name, @phone_number =n.phone_number, @messagepriority =n.messagepriority, @phone_id=n.phone_id , 
                                                                          @AD_show=n.AD_show, @power_show=n.power_show
                                                                    FROM 
                                                                          #temporary_phonetable n WITH(NOLOCK) 
                                                                    WHERE n.rownumber = @rownumber

                                                                    SET @record_no = AddMessageToQueue(@phone_number, @responsemessages, @dateresponsessent, @savednames, @userid, un.messagepriority, @responsetype, 
                                                                    un.AD_show, un.power_show, @service_provider, @PhoneType)  


                                                                    If(@questionid > 0)
                                                                    BEGIN 
                                                                            SET @questionMessage = AddQuestionMessage(@questionid,@phone_id,  @record_no, DATEADD(d, 30, GETDATE()) )
                                                                    END 


                                            UPDATE #temporary_phonetable SET record_no = @record_no, questionMessage=@questionMessage WHERE phone_number = @phone_number  AND rownumber = @rownumber
                                END
```

Comment: Nail down what in your (lengthy)  posted code is causing the slowdown, and we might be able to help.

Comment: The slow down starts at the WHILE LOOP. Right before then, the code runs approximately 0.16 secs. As soon as it hits the While loop, there is a 25 minutes increase in processing time

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique constraint to `rownumber` in your temp table. Rewrite the `WHILE` as a `CTE`. Use `APPLY` to call the functions.

Comment: Doesn't this count? UNIQUE (questionMessage, record_no, rownumber).  Or is this not what you mean?

Comment: Not really. You want to make this really fast: WHERE n.rownumber = @rownumber. A unique constraint or index on this field can do wonders. It you need really performance continue with getting rid of the loop.

Comment: Also want to add that AddMessageToQueue and AddQuestionQueue are STOREDPROCS and not Functions.

Comment: Nested stored procs in a loop. Yikes. Start by rewriting the nested procs as Inline Functions.

Comment: There is a lot of processing to happen in the code(about 50 addition lines worth). That is why I removed that portion into a separate stored proc of it's own. You are saying that instead I should copy all that code back into this main proc?

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to consider using a table variable rather than a temporary table. You won't be writing to the tempdb and as table variables are created in memory they're faster.

[This article](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html) has a nice comparison.

Comment: I tried this but not much of a difference still. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Instead of a while loop checking row by row against the table variable, you could INSERT..SELECT the database where the conditions have been met. If you also need to know which rows did not meet the criteria you could reverse the conditions to find that out.

Comment: If you look at the query loop, I am having to actually execute a stored procedure for each line there that is why I have the loop. I know I can't execute that for each line with INSERT. . . .SELECT, or can I?

Comment: What I'm saying is try to take that logic out of the procedure and instead of applying it on a row by row basis, apply it to the whole table at once.